# C++ (hash) map speed optimization

Tags: c++, performance, hashmap

I'm creating a game but I'm having trouble with map performance.

On every render/update call, I have to loop through every chunk in the list.
When I move over the chunk border, a few chunks (just those that are required to be added or removed) will be added and removed to the list (one by one).

This takes too long and impacts my games performance quite bad. If I remove the update loop my FPS increases by 100!

```
for(pair<const DWORD, Chunk*>& pair : loadedChunks){
    Chunk* c = pair.second;
    if(c != NULL){
        c->update(delta); //Does totally nothing
    }
}
```

(There are 205 chunks in the list atm.)

This is my current implementation:

```
unordered_map<DWORD, Chunk*> loadedChunks;

void ChunkManager::addChunk(int x, int y, int z){
    Chunk* chunk = new Chunk(this, x, y, z);
    rebuildChunks.push_back(chunk);
    loadedChunks.emplace(((x & 0xFFFF)) << 16 | ((y & 0xFFFF) << 8) | (z & 0xFFFF), chunk);
}

void ChunkManager::removeChunk(int x, int y, int z){
    long key = ((x & 0xFFFF)) << 16 | ((y & 0xFFFF) << 8) | (z & 0xFFFF);
    delete loadedChunks[key];
    loadedChunks.erase(key);
}

Chunk* ChunkManager::getChunkAt(int x, int y, int z){
    if(loadedChunks.find(((x & 0xFFFF)) << 16 | ((y & 0xFFFF) << 8) | (z & 0xFFFF)) != loadedChunks.end()){
        return loadedChunks[((x & 0xFFFF)) << 16 | ((y & 0xFFFF) << 8) | (z & 0xFFFF)];
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a faster map or if maybe I'm doing something wrong in my implementation.

I'm willing to use an external lib if that is the only way possible.

Another possibility is some way of using the `std::vector` list with XYZ;

Note:

The hash key: ((x & 0xFFFF)) << 16 | ((y & 0xFFFF) << 8) | (z & 0xFFFF).
Is not anywhere near perfect as it only allows values from 0 - 255 but it works for now and its better then using string as the performance for string are even worse according to this [article](http://kariddi.blogspot.nl/2012/07/c11-unorderedmap-vs-map.html)

.

Edit:

In the comments it was noted that FPS isn't a good indicator so I've used this timer:

```
unsigned int start = clock();
for(pair<const DWORD, Chunk*>& pair : loadedChunks){
    Chunk* c = pair.second;
    if(c != NULL){
        c->update(delta);
    }
}
unsigned int timepassed = clock() - start;
OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR) wstring(to_wstring(timepassed) + L"\n").c_str());
```

And the ouput was between 1 & 2 milliseconds. (thats about as long as my rendering takes.. just for looping through a list of 205 items)

Edit 2:

I've decided I'll just reduce the amount of loops by adding a timer:

```
tickTimer+=delta;
if(tickTimer >= 0.05){
    for(pair<const DWORD, Chunk*>& pair : loadedChunks){
        pair.second->update(delta);
    }
    tickTimer = 0;
}
```

This way it will only run 20 times a second.

Edit 3:

@brianbeuning Had a very good point, I was using MSVS and was using debug mode, That way all code runs very slow.

Comment: Just looping through the list takes a very long time.
As you can see in the fist piece of code, the update method does totally noting so that can't decrease the FPS.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae I've added a little edit in addition to the FPS indicator

Comment: If it really, really is the iteration time (which I have my doubts about), then ammend your data structure to be a combination of an unordered_map and a doubly linked list.  The latter being only used for the main loop iterations.  Each chunk would point to it's own position in the linked list.  add/remove operations would modify both the hash table and the linked list.

Comment: Iterate over the buckets one at a time and report how many elements are in each bucket.  That will tell us if the problem is the hash or not.  I can't imagine what else it would be, besides paging.

Comment: @selbie The list is only used in the chunk manager and is private so the chunks it self can't point to a position in the list

Comment: @MooingDuck I have no idea how I should do that, do you have an example? (sorry)

Comment: Is `Chunk` a polymorphic base class? If it isn't, there is no need for the indirection. Just store `Chuck` instead of `Chuck*` as values.

Comment: Also, about the 3D array idea, that will take 64 or 128 MB of memory, depending on the size of an int on your platform. Your cache hierarchy probably won't like it.

Comment: I've tried the 3D array just yet, but it has the same speed.

Comment: @FredOverflow Regarding the *, I create a new Chunk() which returns a pointer.

Comment: If you are developing using debug mode code, the STL code is much slower in debug mode.

Comment: @brianbeuning YOU SIR, ARE A HERO. No sorry, but serious, thats probably why its soo slow...

Comment: @Duckdoom5: Oh, yeah.  MSVC uses special iterators in debug mode that run very very very slowly, but tell if you have certain types of bugs.  That's probably relevant.  Try a release build to find out.

Comment: @Duckdoom5 "I create a `new Chunk()` which returns a pointer" - So? `Chunk()` doesn't. You may want to know that `new` is superseded by less bug-prone, and in some cases, faster alternatives.

Comment: I'll try a release build in a second, will edit afterward

Comment: `for(size_t i=0; i<loadedChunks.bucket_count(); ++i) std::cout << loadedChunks.bucket_size(i) << ' ';`  To iterate over the buckets and report the sizes

Comment: @MooingDuck This is part of the result (couldn't fit), there are a few 4's and 3's later: 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 2 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 2 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0

Comment: @Duckdoom5: Well, that looks pretty good.  As long as they're all under 10 or so, that's not the issue.  My bet is on the debug mode thing.

Comment: I've tried a release build but I get an Access violation reading location 0x00000000. Null pointer at my camera matrix code. So I have to investigate that before I can tell if the release build solved the problem. Any way I'm very tired so I'm gonna go to bed. Thanks for the help I'll continue tomorrow.

Comment: @MooingDuck I've fixed the problems, the XMMATRIX type can't be properly used with a 32bit release. Had to use the XMFLOAT4X4. *Me and my silly need for fixing stuff before I go to bed*.

The release build seems to have a lot of impact on the speed of the code as the FPS is almost doubled. Didn't do a timer test yet, but I'm sure its way faster.

Comment: @Duckdoom5 Of course release is faster. That's the whole point of release :)

Answer (score 0):

My psychic powers suggest that there are more items in the map than you think.  Perhaps a bug elsewhere in your program is not removing the items from the map.

Modify your main loop:

```
int count = 0;
int nullcount = 0;
for(pair<const DWORD, Chunk*>& pair : loadedChunks){
    Chunk* c = pair.second;
    if(c != NULL){
        c->update(delta);
        count++;
    }
    else {
        nullcount++;
    }
}
unsigned int timepassed = clock() - start;
OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR) wstring(to_wstring(timepassed) + L"  items:" +  to_wstring(count) + L"   nullitems" +  to_wstring(nullcount) + L"\n").c_str());
```

Now what does it print?

Comment: it prints: `1  items:205   nullitems0`

Comment: @Duckdoom5 - sorry.  My psychic powers have failed me.  But I've got another alternative for you.  You can use my fasthash template class. It's a classic hash table implementation, but it works by only allocating memory once, which means you give it the max size of elements in the constructor or as a template parameter. It was written for a server project where the std::* collection classes had poor performance because of non-deterministic memory allocations.  Code is at: https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/common/fasthash.h  and example is at: http://collabedit.com/9k8n7

Comment: Looks very interesting, I'll try it if my newest approach doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how good the compiler you are using at optimization, but you are evaluating the same thing twice both in removeChunk() and in getChunkAt(). for example, in getChunkAt first you should store the iterator returned by `loadedChunks.find()`, then in a separate statement test if it is NULL, and if it's not, return its `->second`. You can do similar optimization in removeChunk().

BTW, I don't know what you do in elsewhere in the code, but in addChunk() you create a new chunk, save it in rebuildChunks *and* put it in the loadedChunks map. However, in removeChunk() you delete the chunk using the pointer in loadedChunks[key], but there is nothing in your snippet that would remove chunk from rebuildChunks. If it is still there you have a dangling pointer...

Comment: Thanks for the small improvements.

This is the rebuild code:

`static double timerr = 0;

void ChunkManager::rebuild(double delta, Renderer& renderer){
 if(timerr > 0){
  timerr -= delta;
 }else if(!rebuildChunks.empty()){
  rebuildChunks.back()->initialize(renderer);
  rebuildChunks.pop_back();

  timerr = 0.01;
 }
}`

So as you can see, its removed.

Answer (score -1):

If the iteration speed is what is important, try using a `map` instead of an `unordered_map` -- the `unordered_map` gives you faster lookup/insert/remove at a cost of greater memory use and slower iteration over the entire map.

Comment: I'd expect the memory overhead of a map of small keys and values to be quite large, and more fragmented than that of a hash map. I guess this is the kind of thing that really needs to be measured.

Comment: I've used a `map` before, that was even worse because I also need to access data fast at loading (`getChunkAt`) and moving (`addChunk` , `removeChunk`)

Comment: _slower iteration over the entire map_ [there is a great overview how iteration works in hash containers](http://bannalia.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/implementation-of-c-unordered.html). Iteration over all elements in a hash container is pretty much the same as iterating a list.

Comment: From that page: _the standard requires that iterator increment be O(1)_